# Looping over table rows and moving contents from one cell to another with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'm trying to loop over TRs and take contents from one cell and append them to another.

```
$('.tableRow').each( function(){
    $( '.cell2', this).wrapInner("<div class='tempDiv'></div>");
    $('.tempDiv', this ).appendTo( ".cell1", this );
});
```

... but what I'm getting is for example, if a table has 4 rows, cell1 will get tempDiv appended at least 8 times.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HenriPablo/TFgN3/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the result you were looking for?

```
$('.tableRow').each( function(){
    $(this).find('.cell2').wrapInner("<div class='tempDiv'></div>");
    $(this).find('.tempDiv').appendTo( $(this).find('.cell1') );
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/kLyHy/

The way it was written, the data from each cell was appended to *each* instance of the class "cell1"...

Comment: yes, what tripped me up was I thought '$( '.cell2', this)' and '$('.tempDiv', this )' specified the current TR in the loop as cont ext for the operation. I was obviously wrong there. Where have I gone wrong specifying the context I'm curious. I was thinking of something that @amit_g did.

Comment: $(this) is always just the element that's defined in the function (in the above function that would be `.tableRow`). To do stuff with the elements _within_ $(this), use selectors like `.children()` or `.find()`.

Comment: By the way, I changed `$('.tempDiv', this )` to `$(this).find('.tempDiv')` It somehow makes more sense to me... (I've actually never written any code that looked like `$('.tempDiv', this )` before...but apparently it works the same way.)

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do this, but the quickest way to get your code to work is to make some changes to the jQuery:

```
$('.tableRow').each( function(){
    $(this).find('.cell2').wrapInner("<div class='tempDiv'></div>");
    $(this).find('.cell1').append($(this).find(".tempDiv"));
});
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Q632/)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [this](http://jsfiddle.net/TFgN3/3/)?

```
$('.tableRow').each( function(){
    $(".cell1", this)
        .append($("<div class='tempDiv'></div>")
                    .append($( '.cell2', this).html())
               );
});
```